# Can a geometry node field exist inside another nodes field? Similar to nested for loops?

Tags: geometry-nodes

While attempting to recreate a Mesh Deform modifier that could function without a bind, I managed to create a setup that would deform a mesh properly when given specific vertex indices from the added input meshes (`CubeDeform`, and `CubeBind`). Based on the documentation I expected the node tree to be repeated for each vertex in the input meshes after connecting an `Index` node to the `Sample Index` node as if in a for loop. Instead, the weight map becomes centered on the Plane and stops deforming.

Is there a way for a field of the Place, to influenced by every vertex in the field of the cube?

**Before and after connecting the Index node**
[image: Working Setup]

[image: Broken Setup with Index Node]

Comment: *"Is there a way for a field of the Place, to influenced by every vertex in the field of the cube?"* - you can use a loop, but you can't use it inside a field, you use it outside the field. So you make a calculation for 1st vertex, then for 2nd vertex etc. and once you calculated it for all vertices, you e.g. sum it all up and divide by number of vertices to get an average.